# What's the main difference between dijkstra's algorithm and Prim's algorithm?

Tags: c, dijkstra, prims-algorithm

I can't find too much difference between **prim's** and **dijkstra's** algorithm. Can anyone explain the main difference of them.

Comment: They aren't even used to solve the same problem...

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). I also suggest the `c` language tag has absolutely nothing to do with this post, and thus question why it was even used.